# Scrolling functionality in Blackberry

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I have 4 buttons 1)left 2)video  3)technical insight  4)right..as seen in the below image.Now I want to provide functionlity to this image.The functionality is

If i click on the left arrow the video technical insight have to scroll to the left and similarly if I click on the right arrow the  the two buttons have to scroll to the right and show two more video names..in Blackberry Simulator
[image: Image on which functionality is to be provided]
Can anyone please help me in writing the code.I would be happy If I can get the code to provide this functionality in Blackberry..

---

I have some ideas regarding this.Do tell me if this can be done or not..

I created left button ,videos button,technicalinsight button and right button in a manager called hfm

When i click on the left button the entire things in hfm will get deleted using hfm.deleteAll() and then repaint it with the hfm which we get after scroll.

Is this idea good or any better approach for this??

Comment: Why don't you start coding and then we help you fixing it o giving you some tips?

Comment: I have some ideas regarding this.Do tell me if this can be done or not..


I created left button ,videos button,technicalinsight button and right button in a manager called hfm 

When i click on the left button the entire things in hfm will get deleted using hfm.deleteAll() and then repaint it with the hfm which we get after scroll.

Is this idea good or any better approach for this??

Comment: try posting some code. And instead of deleteAll() You can also think of replace. Maybe it would be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

you can Override the paint() method and use graphics.drawBitmap to redraw the screen.